# QGIS 3.4 Mac Layout Font problem

Tags: mac, layouts, font, qgis-3

Long time qgis mac user.  I find with qgis 3.4, it will not change fonts within the Layout text box, nor will it show ESRI North arrows when I choose that font in a text box.
When I deleted 3.4 and reloaded 3.2 Bonn all the fonts are working as before.
Has this been noted and been fixed?  I cant use 3.4 at this point.

QGIS 3 is a vast improvement over 2.18.   Congratulations to the development team.

Tanoos

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem. This bug report [Font will not resize in QGIS Print Layout](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20426) discusses the issue.

This answer from Jonas Küpper worked for me

> "The problem is basically that changes you make to fonts using "Text
>   Format" dialog are not applied. Only when you use the dropdown menu,
>   you can change font styles."

If you click on the word `'Font'` under Appearance it brings up the Text Format dialog. Those changes do not work.

If you click on the down arrow to the right of the box with `'Font'` you get a different drop down, and changes in that set (including loading the Text Format dialogue from there) are applied.